# keep fixed position of text input when hide/show border

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want my input textfields to look like plain old text until they are moused over.

I accomplish this with this little bit of code (also available here on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebidot/2/edit))

```
layerTitleJq.hover( function( evt ) {
      layerTitleJq.css( 'border', "" );
   },
   function( evt ){ 
      layerTitleJq.css( 'border', 0 );
})
```

The aesthetic problem is that when you hover, the text in the textfield gets pushed over a pixel or two when the borders show up.  Wondering how to keep that text *in the exact same spot* during hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle `border-color` instead:

```
layerTitleJq.hover( function( evt ) {
      $(this).removeAttr('style');
   },
   function( evt ){ 
      $(this).css( 'border-color', 'transparent' ); // invisible border
})
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/637C4))

But a better way would be to [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) a class. When the class is present make the border visible. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/637C4/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

Comment: You will have to manually give padding to the inputbox on hover out state and then remove it on hover

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by adding padding when there is in no border, and when there is border, remove the padding.

```
layerTitleJq.hover( function( evt ) {
    layerTitleJq.css( 'border', "" ).css( 'padding', "0px" );
}, function( evt ){
    layerTitleJq.css( 'border', 0 ).css( 'padding', "2px" );
})
```

By the way, you could do all this with CSS ....

```
.ui-corner-all {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.ui-corner-all:hover {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
}
```